# How do I fix this deadlock in Win Forms constructor when using async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, deadlock, async-await

Here is my minimum repro case:

```
public Form1()
{
    Task.Delay(100).Wait();  // Works just fine

    this.Await().Wait();     // Blocks indefinitely
}

private async Task Await()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

What is going on here?  Why are these two behaving differently?  What can I do to make the later one work?

My actual case is less trivial, and I can't "just use the first option".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing a classic deadlock situation that I describe [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In short, after the `await` completes, the `async` method is attempting to resume on the UI thread, which you have blocked by calling `Wait`.

To fix it, you ideally want to use `async` all the way (i.e., never block on `async` code). Constructors pose a difficulty here (since they cannot be `async`); I explore several options [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). The correct option depends on your code base, but I recommend the `async` factory method if possible. The options are:

- Async factory method.
- Asynchronous lazy initialization.
- Asynchronous initialization pattern.

If you absolutely cannot use one of the options that I describe on my blog, then you can work around this by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in all your `async` methods, and then your `Wait()` will not deadlock. However, this *will* block the UI thread during those asynchronous method calls (which sort of defeats the purpose of them being `async` in the first place...)

Comment: I figured that this had something to do with the `[STAThread]`-ness of the thread that the constructor was running in.  I worked around this by dependency injecting the constructor AFTER the task has completed, but this is less than ideal.

Comment: Yes, sort of. The behavior is actually enforced by the `WinFormsSynchronizationContext`, which is centered around a single UI thread.